# Where does Python 3 gethostbyname look for host name translations?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to use sockets to reach my Apache server hosted on a guest VM in a Python program.

I have modified my Macs `/etc/hosts` file to include my Apache servers IP address under the name `vulnerable/`.  I have confirmed that my DNS entry works in both Google Chrome and Safari.

My problem is when I try to use `socket.gethostbyname("vulnerable/")` Python throws `socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.

Where is `gethostbyname`, and any of the other socket related `get` commands looking for these translations?

Comment: I think you need to remove the backslash from `vulnerable/`.

Comment: Hmm. The answer given, while useful to you, isn't likely to help anyone else who wants to know about the backend used by gethostbyname(). Maybe you should modify the title to reflect your *real* question (the one which the answer addresses)?

Comment: I am still curious as to where Python looks to find these translations.  The specific problem with my code led me to wonder as to where exactly it looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slashes are not permitted in hostnames.

See [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) for full details of what is allowed for a hostname.

Comment: That was it!  I guess I was including that because both Chrome and Safari saw it as a search query instead of a hostname.  Thanks!